# Which force:* events must I declare as <aura:dependency>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-events

I'm confused when to use `<aura:dependency resource="force..">` and when not?

If my component is using on of the following system events does it need to be explicitly declared as dependency?

- `force:closeQuickAction`
- `force:createRecord`
- `force:navigateToSObject`
- `force:showToast`
- ...

I remember having read that system events are somewhat autodiscovered but [in some open source repos (e.g. Strike Components)](https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/blob/fb28075b586d3e2c2ea2d98c8dba833767f10df2/aura/strike_lookup/strike_lookup.cmp#L71) I found components declaring them explicitly.

Comment: That's an interesting question, I thought using aura:registerEvent was doing this dependency job.

Comment: As I understand the docs and code examples out there aura:registerEvent is only for custom events your components might trigger. Compared to java registerEvent is throws and dependency is catch.

Comment: Isn't catch aura:handler ? To me aura:dependency was just for performance purpose, to be sure the definition of the event/component is sent to the browser.

Comment: The only time I have ever needed to declare them was when using Lightning Out. That is not to say it is the only time it is needed (I have not come close to any advanced use cases AFAIK) but with straight lightning it seems to know what is required without declaring a dependency

Answer (score 1):

The system automatically detects a component's dependencies through several mechanism and ensures they're available on the client when it needs them.

`<aura:dependency>` is for advanced use cases where you need explicit control over prefetching of definitions. Using this effectively requires careful consideration and performance analysis.

I highly recommend not using them until you have a clear data-based need to control definition prefetching.